# Interaction of diamagnetic material in external applied field

Tags: electromagnetism

**How much magnetic field should i apply so that i can see repulsion effect of diamagnetic material at room temperature?**

Comment: You need this to see levitation with permanent magnets: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrolytic_carbon